# Not getting the correct values for variables in extended class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, polymorphism, extend

Just doing a quick edit up at the top of my post.
The question is if i extend a class and both classes have the same variable why is the extended class getting the original classes value.

This has been answered but would be more than happy to read more information about this. 
Polymorphism isn't a strong suit of my so i'm having to relearn this stuff after not using it for months.

So i'm trying to program a game and one of the requirements is some type of list of object that can be scanned in a loop. The trouble starts with my test of ArrayList. I have 3 classes i made to be added in to my array list. Entities, Monster extends Entities, and Character extends Entities. do note Monster and Character both extends Entities class.
I decided that i should make the ArrayList and added new objects directly in to each element(the word element is normally used with array not ArrayList correct?) and use a log function i programmed to note down values of the objects in the ArrayList. 
I made a for loop and ran both Monster and Character .getHP() method that they inherited from Entities and the results was the HP from Entities not Monster or Character unless i added a new value to the classes HP using the setHP(int i) method also inherited Entities.

Since my program requires most of the classes and we only need about 99% i decided to make a test project to basically do the above in a smaller form since i don't want to be copying pasting 20 or more .java files here. Anyways here's my test classes and results.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    // class to test interactions between Extended classes
    public class testHP {
        ArrayList<Entities> ent = new ArrayList<Entities>();

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ///make reference varaible so i don't have to make test() and ent static. 
            testHP hp = new testHP();
            hp.test();
        }
        void test(){
            /// the 3 classes to the arraylist. I could of made a reference variable but didn't.
            this.ent.add(new Character());
            this.ent.add(new Monster());
            this.ent.add(new NPC());
            ///prints out whats in the array list so i know that i have the correct objects.
            System.out.println(this.ent);

            /// this prints out { ent(i) HP "is" i } to tell which class is being called and it's HP at this point.
            for(int i=0; i<ent.size();i=i+1) {System.out.println(this.ent.get(i).getHP() +" is "+ this.ent.get(i));}
            /// this adds i plus 10 then does the same as the last for loop.
            for(int i=0; i<ent.size();i=i+1) {
                this.ent.get(i).gainHP(i+10);
                System.out.println(this.ent.get(i).getHP() +" is "+ this.ent.get(i));}
        }
    }



abstract public class Entities {
    private int HP = 1;

    int getHP(){
        return HP;
    }
    void gainHP(int hp){
        HP = this.HP + hp;
    }
}



///Character is to show what happens when i change the value and make it static.
public class Character extends Entities {
    private static int HP = 4;
}


///monster is to show a changed variable from the super which is entities.
public class Monster extends Entities {
    private int HP = 4;

}

/// NPC is a class that just to have variables from entities class that aren't edited or made static. 
public class NPC extends Entities {

}
```

here is my results with these files as they are above. I should have put HP next to the number to the left but you get the idea.

```
[Character@67f1fba0, Monster@3fbefab0, NPC@133c5982]
1 is Character@67f1fba0
1 is Monster@3fbefab0
1 is NPC@133c5982
11 is Character@67f1fba0
12 is Monster@3fbefab0
13 is NPC@133c5982
```

My test class for the original ArrayList looks like this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class AreaMap extends Map {


    String CLASS = "Area Map";///log requires.
    ArrayList<Entities> ent = new ArrayList<Entities>();    
    AreaMap(){
        Log.Logging(CLASS,"Testing arrayList");

        //random text added to the array.
        ent.add(new Character());
        ent.add(new Monster());
        Log.Logging(CLASS, "ent 1 has " +ent+ " in it");
        for(int i=0; i < ent.size();i = i+1){
        Log.Logging(CLASS, "ArrayList " + this.ent.get(i).getHealth() +" i="+i);
        }
        for(int i=0; i < ent.size();i = i+1){
            this.ent.get(i).setHP(10+i);
        Log.Logging(CLASS, "ArrayList " + this.ent.get(i).getHealth() +" i="+i);
        }
    }
}
```

And here are my result from that.

```
[Area Map]##[Testing arrayList]
[Area Map]##[ent 1 has [Character@2bd1e730, Monster@61a116c9] in it]
[Area Map]##[ArrayList 0 i=0]
[Area Map]##[ArrayList 0 i=1]
[Area Map]##[ArrayList 10 i=0]
[Area Map]##[ArrayList 11 i=1]
```

Do note that "Log" is a class i made and the method is "static Logging(String origin, String Action){System.out.println([origin]+"##"+[Action]);"
origin is always the class not that it has to be.

Sorry if this isn't clear. If you need more information to help me i'm more than willing to answer.

Comment: Sorry JayCD I may have glanced through your post too quickly, but is there any questions in it? (besides this one: the word element is normally used with array not ArrayList correct?)

Comment: Sorry it seems explain what going on but didn't really ask the question. I want to know if i extend a class why are the instance variables the same as the ones in my super class. I would expect this if i wasn't over riding but i was. John below says i can't do it and that seems to support my experience with these classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the problem is that you're trying to declare extra variables in subclasses as if they can "override" the variable in the superclass. Variables don't work that way - they're not polymorphic.

If you need to give each class a different starting number of hit points, I suggest you create a `protected` constructor in `Entities` (which should be renamed, btw - e.g. `AbstractEntity`) to take the initial value of `HP` (which should probably be renamed `hitPoints`). Then each subclass would have a public constructor to call the superconstructor with an appropriate value.

For example:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    private int hitPoints;

    protected AbstractEntity(int initialHitPoints) {
        this.hitPoints = initialHitPoints;
    }

    public int getHitPoints(){
        return hitPoints
    }

    void gainHitPoints(int amount) {
        hitPoints += amount;
    }
}

public class Monster extends AbstractEntity {
    public Monster() {
        // Every monster starts off with 4 hit points
        super(4);
    }
}
```

Now that's just a matter of changing the initial state. If you wish the different entities to *behave* differently, you should override the abstract class methods within the subclasses.

Comment: Perfect. I know what to do and how avoid this mistake in the feature.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is scoping. The `HP` that `Entities`* is accessible from your `getHP`, but your `HP` in `Character` and `Monster` are different variables that happen to have the same name. Additionally, marking `HP` as `private` means that subclasses can't access that variable - I think you have `protected`.

What is probably the correct solution to get rid of HP in Monster and Character, make HP in Entities protected, and set the default HP in the default constructor for Monster and Character.

* It's good style to name your objects in the singular, so this is better named as `Entity`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, the problem is as follows:

You declared the attribute `HP` as private in class Entities and declared a new(!) variable in the subclass (see the other answers).

You can resolve the behavior by setting HP by a constructors, e. g.,

```
class Entitites {
  private int HP;

  public Entities(int hp) {
    this.HP = hp;
  }
}

class Monster extends Entities {
  public Monster() {
    super(4);
  }
}
```